# Constant Acceleration Due to Gravity?

Tags: field-theory

I was considering the behavior of a scalar field $\phi$ when influenced by the sudden introduction of a particle. To do this, I modeled the Lagrangian density by a scalar field in spacetime with a particle introduced at event ($x_0$, $t_0$), which is: \begin{equation}\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi^\mu-g\delta(x-x_0)H(t-t_0)\phi(x_0, t_0).\end{equation}
Where $H$ is the Heaviside function and $\delta$ is Dirac's delta function. When I plug the field into the Euler-Lagrange equation, I get this:
\begin{equation}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}-c^2\Delta\phi = -g\delta(x-x_0)H(t-t_0).\end{equation}
This is an inhomogenous wave equation, and because of the linearity of the equation, it's specific solution superimposes over the scalar field that was there. Thus, we can consider the effect of the particle's introduction in isolation. The contribution is:
\begin{equation}\phi(x, t) = -g\int\int_V\delta(x-x_0)H(t-t_0)d^4x,\end{equation}
where V is the four-dimensional past light cone of the event $(x, t)$. Solving, we get:
\begin{equation}\phi(x, t) = -g(\lvert t-t_0\rvert-\frac{1}{c}\lvert x-x_0\rvert)H(\lvert t-t_0\rvert-\frac{1}{c}\lvert x-x_0\rvert).\end{equation}
Another particle would experience a force $-g'\nabla\phi$, where $g'$ is the coupling constant of the new particle. In the case of gravity, by the equivalence principle, this implies:
\begin{equation}a = -\frac{g}{c}\frac{x-x_0}{\lvert x-x_0\rvert}H(\lvert t-t_0\rvert-\frac{1}{c}\lvert x-x_0\rvert).\end{equation}
However, I was expecting the typical
\begin{equation}a = -gG\frac{x-x_0}{\lvert x-x_0\rvert ^3}.\end{equation}
What is the reason for this discrepancy? One explanation I had devised was that we perceive a higher acceleration of objects closer to the particle because they were accelerated for longer periods of time than those farther (due to the Heaviside function). It might also be due to the fact that particles may not "pop" into space. The latter depends on the way antiparticles are coupled to gravity.

Comment: How did you expect $G$ to suddenly appear in algebra that never had it?

Comment: G would be some constant that we make equivalent to other constants once the parallel with Newton's gravity is found.

Comment: Also, again due to the linearity of the wave equation, we may multiply the solution by any constant. The emphasis is mostly on the way acceleration varies over space.

Comment: Gravity is not even a force and it's certainly not a scalar force. You can pop any number of "particles" into existence as you like, but unless they are coupled by either boson or fermion statistics OR there is an explicit interaction term in your Hamiltonian they wouldn't know about each other. Why? Because there are no particles to begin with. Quantum mechanics is about quantized energy exchanges. Boson/fermion statistics is a symmetry property and so is the interaction Hamiltonian. If you don't tell your theory what that symmetry is, it can't produce its effects.